# how to restrict launch method calling in sencha touch

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

I am trying to implement orientation in sencha touch application by using **onOrientationchange**
then while running application on device screen is rotate and redirect to my home screen instated of current working screen.

```
onOrientationchange: function(viewport, orientation, width, height) {
    if(width > height){
        orientation = 'landscape';
    }
    else {
        orientation = 'portrait';
    }
    if(orientation == 'landscape' && this.getMyContainer() != undefined ){
        //remove all the items from the main panel
        this.setOrientation(Ext.widget(currentLayout));
    }
    if(orientation == 'portrait' && this.getMyContainer() != undefined){
        this.setOrientation(Ext.widget(currentLayout));
    }
},
```

launch: function(){}

My problem Is launch() is calling in all cases when screen is Rotated in Device.
Please suggest me to solve my problem.
Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Did u tried using phonegap.

```
   onFirstViewRouteLoad: function() {
     if(Ext.os.is.Android || Ext.os.is.iOS ){
        navigator.screenOrientation.set('portrait');
    }

    if('firstview') {

        myApp.util.showActiveItem(Ext.Viewport, 'firstview');
    }
    else {

         myApp.util.showActiveItem(Ext.Viewport, {xtype: 'firstview'});
    }
},
```

Followed by [this](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2011/11/4/PhoneGap-Orientation-Example) post

Comment: Actually my problem is not like this,while i am in second view then reload launch function on controller.

Comment: i updated my answer. I will set orientation during run time is given above. ShowActiveItem which help to set the view in viewport. Try this.

Comment: Hi Guys,
Finally i got solution
Please update android manifest.xml file 
   <activity
            android:name="com.example.inspectionapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            **android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"**>

Comment: Good try finally u got it